# Get Low or custom Resolution images from keyword search of Wikipedia api

Tags: api, wikipedia, mediawiki-api

I am using the Wikipedia API to get image's url from a keyword search. But image url gives the high resolution image. I want the low resolution image. Is there any property I could use to get low or custom resolution images? Below is my API url:

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=New+York&generator=images&gimlimit=max&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=comment|url|dimensions&format=json

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can just add `&iiurlwidth=X`to get a link called "thumburl" to thumb width X pixel width. For you example and 200 pixels it would be:

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=New+York&generator=images&gimlimit=max&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=comment|url|dimensions&format=json&iiurlwidth=200